# mvn package jboss-as:deploy failing

Tags: maven, jboss, jboss7.x, maven-plugin

This is my plugin information in pom.xml

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.2.Final</version>
        </plugin>
```

I have downloaded the jboss AS 7.0.2 on my laptop under the /jboss folder (Mac OSX)
Although I am able to it as a local server on my Eclipse IDE and am able to run my projects via that.I wanted to give a try with mvn jboss-as:deploy.

And it gives this error :

```
[INFO] --- jboss-as-maven-plugin:7.0.2.Final:deploy (default-cli) @ propertyfinder ---
[INFO] Executing goal deploy on server localhost (127.0.0.1) port 9999.
Apr 3, 2014 2:08:50 AM org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl <clinit>
INFO: JBoss Remoting version 3.2.0.Beta2
Apr 3, 2014 2:08:50 AM org.xnio.Xnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO Version 3.0.0.Beta2
Apr 3, 2014 2:08:50 AM org.xnio.nio.NioXnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.0.Beta2
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 8.446s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Apr 03 02:08:55 EDT 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jboss.as.plugins:jboss-as-maven-plugin:7.0.2.Final:deploy (default-cli) on project propertyfinder: Could not execute goal deploy on propertyfinder.war. Reason: Could not connect to remote://localhost:9999 in 5000ms. Make sure the server is running and/or consider setting a longer timeout by setting -Dorg.jboss.as.client.connect.timeout=<timeout in ms>. -> [Help 1]
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is your server up and running? You must start your local server manually before executing the deploy goal or by using jboss-as:start

Comment: how do i start it manually? I cant find a script under /jboss/jboss-as-web-7/bin .  And mvn jboss-as:start gave me this error : 
[ERROR] Could not find goal 'start' in plugin org.jboss.as.plugins:jboss-as-maven-plugin:7.0.2.Final among available goals deploy, redeploy, undeploy, deploy-artifact

Comment: the script is bin/standalone.sh . Anyway you can use jboss maven plugin 7.5.Final that has the jboss-as:start goal

Comment: FWIW though the start goal only lasts the lifecycle of the maven. Once maven exits the server is shutdown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are starting with JBOSS. Before starting JBOSS application server. add the management user

1. Refer [link](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-as-7/adding-users-with-jboss-as-7) to add management user.
2. Start Server by running standalone.bat( windows) or standalone.sh(linux) under bin directory
3. You can quickly verify if the server is started or not by logging into home page `http://localhost:9990/console`.
4. In the log verify if port 9999 is listening which is used for deployment( a default configuration, else you can check which port is listening for remoting)
5. Use the following maven plug-in configuration. user name and password is the management user and password

   ```
   <plugin>
       <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>${jboss.as.plugin.version}</version>
       <configuration>
           <hostname>localhost</hostname>
           <username>{user name}</username>
           <password>{password}</password>
           <port>9999</port>
       </configuration>
   </plugin>
   ```
6. You can use either jboss-as:deploy or jboss-as:redeploy

Comment: Thanks for the reply. A question entirely different from above.The command being jboss-as:deploy could that be used with jboss eap 6.1 server also? Or is it just for jboss as servers?

Comment: Yes, it can be used with EAP 6.x as well as JBoss AS 7.x.